# Only display items on front page (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sorry for the awful title, I couldn't think of anything better.

Basically I have this code:

```
<div id="slideshow-side-tab">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bg-slideshow.png"/>
        <div id="slideshow">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/image-1.jpg" alt="" class="active" />
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/image-2.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/image-3.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/image-4.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
</div>
```

However I only want this to display when the user is on the front page of Wordpress. The homepage has been set to a static page created from within wordpress and I can't just copy this code into the page as it only accepts HTML in the page editor. How can I make this happen?

I have had a look on Wordpress and I found this:

```
<?php
if (is_home()) {
    // This is a homepage
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>
```

But that doesn't seem to work if I place my code in place of the '// This is a homepage'.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()`.

Comment: If I put the code in there it will display a syntax error in Aptana on the first character of the first line of my slideshow code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy / paste your page.php. Than create a separate template file where you can insert your code for the slideshow or a custom field for it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

or

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>

<div id="slideshow-side-tab">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/bg-slideshow.png"/>
        <div id="slideshow">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/image-1.jpg" alt="" class="active" />
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/image-2.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/image-3.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/image-4.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```